# How do I synchronize BigDecimal.add?

Tags: java, synchronization, bigdecimal

I realized that the code below is not thread safe...

```
BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(0.0);

BigDecimal bar = new BigDecimal(10.00);

foo = foo.add(bar)
```

If I updated the code to this:

```
BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(0.0);

BigDecimal bar = new BigDecimal(10.00);

synchronized (this) {
foo = foo.add(bar)
}
```

Would it make the code thread safe? Sorry for the dumb question

Comment: If those are local variables, then the initial code _is_ thread safe.  You only need to be concerned about thread safety when you're working with objects that are referenced by fields, or when multiple threads are created within the method where the variables are declared.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for the error! I misread about that. I am indeed using local variables, however I seem to be running into an issue where my methods are adding up to the wrong amount if there are multiple concurrent users. I'll investigate further on the cause though.

Answer (score -1):

To make such an operation atomic, you can use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html):

```java
AtomicReference<BigDecimal> foo = new AtomicReference<>(new BigDecimal(10.0));

...
foo.accumulateAndGet(bar, (f, b) -> f.add(b));
```

But that's basically the same as synchronizing the block on `this`:

```
synchronized (this) {
    foo = foo.add(bar);
}
```

Comment: *"same as synchronizing the block on `foo`"?* Certainly not. Let's say 3 threads arrive at the same time, so 2 of the threads are blocked on `BigDecimal` object #1, and the lucky thread changes the value of `foo` to `BigDecimal` object #2, and release `BigDecimal` object #1. The other two threads now execute in parallel, both obtaining `BigDecimal` object #2 and both replacing with `BigDecimal` objects #3 and #4, **race condition** determines which wins. Result: Effect of one of the threads is discarded. *Oops!!*

Comment: @Andreas indeed! I didn't consider that. I suppose synchronizing on a separate object that never changes (the OP uses `this`, I guess that works?) would be what I had in mind, then?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it would work exactly as you describe. wouldn't thread 3 need to reach the synchronized block after the reference to foo has changed? otherwise, wouldn't it be waiting to acquire the first same foo that thread 2 is also waiting on? (I think thread #2 needs to be waiting to obtain object #1, but thread #3 must arrive as `foo` is object #2, so that thread #2 and #3 can actually run in parallel, no?)

Comment: You're right, T3 needs to arrive after T1 changes `foo` value to O2, at which point T2 (lock on O1) and T3 (lock on O2) are racing each other.